# vs2003: build issue with very large solution

Tags: visual-studio

My VS2003 , C#, solution has close to 230 projects. Building this sln takes a long time. What would you recommend that I do to build it more efficiently. What are the best practices to effectively isolate issues as I encounter while building.

Plus, I just work here and can not simply upgrade to VS2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really *have* to have 230 projects all in the same solution? Options I'd consider:

- Merge some projects. If you've got lots of projects with just a few classes, consider combining them.
- Separate the projects into different solutions. This will mean changing the way your dependencies work (from project-based to location-based) but means each solution should build reasonably quickly.

Of course, if you could look at your build log and work out where the time is going, that would help too.

Comment: Jon, thanks for response. I do not have the option of breaking down the sln. Also, I am not familiar with what all the projects are doing and would not know how to combine them into smaller solution. Any other ideas?